# C++: Is this the proper way to delete a linked list recursively?

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I was wondering if this is correct, since XCode gives me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when doing getNext(), but Visual Studio doesn't.

```
void deleteList(LinkedList* node) {

    if (node == NULL)
        return;
    else {
        delete node;
        node=NULL;
        deleteList(node->getNext());
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `node->getNext()` to mean when you know that `node` is `NULL` (because that's what you set it to one statement earlier) i.e. do you think that `((LinkedList*)NULL)->getNext()` is correct?

Comment: Okay that makes sense! I didn't see that before. Thanks! Edit: Tested it out, this is the correct answer.

Comment: The proper recursive way to do `void f(XTYPE x) { if(basecase(x)) return; else {reduce(&x); f(x);} }` is `void f(XTYPE x) { while (!basecase(x)) {reduce(&x)} return; }`: tail recursion :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You delete a node, nullify it, and then use it to call `getNext()`. That's undefined behavior.

Simply do the same work in the nodes destructor.

```
struct NodeT
{
  NodeT* next;
  ~NodeT()
  {
    delete next;
  }
};
```

Either that, or first delete the tail, and only then the node itself:

```
void deleteList(LinkedList* node) {

    if (node == NULL)
        return;
    else {
        deleteList(node->getNext());
        delete node;
    }
}
```

Comment: The 2nd part worked for me. Just a question: would setting node=NULL do anything more? I'm not sure what the point of using it is.

Comment: @RyanEdwardDougherty Well, deleting a null pointer is harmless, so that prevents calling delete on the same address again. It also prevents a dangling reference. But since `node` is local, and you don't use it again, there isn't much point to nullify it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `node` to `NULL` is normally a way to let the system know it's empty. Setting a `NULL` node usually makes your program safer, since the compiler or IDE may notify you that it's a `NULL` node when you try to delete a `NULL` node. For a deeper understanding, you can look for some instruction about empty pointers.

Comment: Why would the IDE notify you!? As per the standard, calling delete on a null pointer does nothing, it's safe.

Comment: It's actually just notice, I'm not sure if it's OK to delete a null pointer in every compiler, because for some of them, I encountered error.